# Is it possible to use aes encryption in a php loop

Tags: php, aes

I have php code examining a database with phone numbers encoded using AES encryption. In some circumstances it arises that the code sees 4 rows in the database that it has to act on, (phone via an sms gateway). Is it possible to decrypt the 4 numbers using an iteration of the AES script or must I wait and reload my code using a once a minute cron job to achieve this. Or should I investigate building a separate class to achieve this. Presently I am getting an error when trying this: Cannot redeclare AES. Or are there particular variable I could unset within the AES class to achieve the recall to decrypt. This is a request for general advice on this issue and not for code.

Code Requested Edit: Database query rows

```
$sms = $row['sms'];
$num = @mysqli_num_rows($rrv);
if($num>0){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rrv, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$price = $row['price'];
$priceLive = $price;
if ($gt_lt == 'GT') {
if ($priceLive > $priceOrder) {
include '1.php';
$sms = $y1;
```

Code for 1.php

```
<?php
include 'AES.php';//Code as at the AES website.
$aes = new AES($sms, '-----', 256);//Input Text, Input Key, Block Size
$y1=$aes->decrypt();//give back to $sms
?>
```

All works if only 1 number needs calling.

Comment: 1. yes it's possible. 2. Show the code.

Comment: Don't declare functions or classes inside a loop...

Comment: @Robert some of the relevant code added as request

Comment: Use `require_once` instead of `include 'AES.php';`
Why don't you use autoloader and classes for your "decoding" methods?

Comment: @Wazelin the require_once worked! Thank you. Add as answer and I will up tick. Do you have a more info on autoloader and classes for decoding. I'll google it, certainly but if you have any direct suggestion, appreciated.

Comment: Read about PSR-4 and composer.
I won't add it as an answer. It's a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

There is error because you cannot include the same class twice and you're doing it in the loop. The best solution would be to use autoloader. The solution that will work and is better than yours comes below

```
include_once 'AES.php';

$sms = $row['sms'];
$num = @mysqli_num_rows($rrv);

if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rrv, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $price = $row['price'];
    $priceLive = $price;

    if ($gt_lt == 'GT') {
        if ($priceLive > $priceOrder) {
           $aes = new AES($sms, '-----', 256);//Input Text, Input Key, Block Size
           $sms = $aes->decrypt();
```

I don't know how your AES class is defined but maybe it's possible to declare object only once and then use it within the same key (and IV depending of your block cipher mode).

What's more:

- Style your code against PSR rules
- Don't use `@` operator you can check if there are errors simply by checking if `$rrv` is not FALSE